# How to make it horizontal scrollable

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, horizontal-scrolling

**the code below is not showing horizontal scroll even if mentioning it in flatList**
I also removed unnecessary imports too

*HomeScreen*:

```
const firstCategory = categories.items[0];

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          horizontal={true}
          data={firstCategory.movies}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.poster }}/>
          )}   
        />
    </View>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

**I'm unable to sort it through, please help!**
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfJa1.jpg)

Comment: Can u also attach the styles that u added to the container and image.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <FlatList
      horizontal
      data={firstCategory.movies}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.poster }}/>
      )}   
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
    />
```

Try to use this

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, It’s a common issue when using React Native Images not to show for some reason. And usually there are 2 main issues to consider.
Source prop and dimensions .

```
 <FlatList  horizontal={true}
          data={firstCategory.movies}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
       <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.poster }}/> )} 
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true} 

            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UM4A.png)